# SlowCheetah not Working with Octopus

Tags: .net, visual-studio, slowcheetah, octopus

I'm using SlowCheetah with the following configurations: Debug | TeamCity | Release.

That means that I have these files on Visual Studio:

1. Web.config
2. Web.Debug.config
3. Web.TeamCity.config
4. Web.Release.config

When I publish the application manually, everthing works fine, but I'm using **Octopus** to deploy, and when it deploys, instead of generating only "Web.config" file, **it is generating both "Web.config" and "Web.Release.config"**.

Both generated files by Octopus are the same as Visual's Studio version, so it seems that SlowCheetah didn't have any effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'when it deploys'? You need to be a bit more specific about the step definition in Octopus.

Comment: Are you talking about the config transform in Octopus here? Or are you using config variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by enabling **Configuration Transform feature** on Octopus:

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files

Answer (score 1):

Slow Cheetah is something the will run during compilation (your machine or the build server) if you set it up. It will transform the Web.config file and if you publish manually (using Visual Studio or copying the publish output directory) then you will be publishing an already transformed file.

If you are using Octopus deploy to perform your deployment, then you will be providing it with a NuGet package. If you are using Octopack all of the .config files that are of type content will be packaged into the *.nuget* file. These will be the source files. You may also see a transformed file being packaged up in the */bin* in the *.nuget* file too.

At the point of Octopus performing the deployment, it will perform any config transformations that are relevant using variables it knows about as well as environmental config transformations (dev.config, test.config). Web.release.config will be run and it will apply to Web.config - You should be able to see this in the logs for the deployment.

[image]

Hope this helps